# Set anaconda as default in Python

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I am trying to set anaconda as default in python. I have seen countless other similar questions but I am not able to understand what exactly to do.
I am running this on mac os

```
which python
```

gives me

`aliased to /usr/bin/python3`

I have saved anaconda in
`/Users/siddhpurohit/anaconda3`
Anaconda is conda 23.7.3
Python is Python 3.9.6

Please help me. I am new at this, and please go step by step.

Comment: is your terminal configured to load anaconda? With [`conda init`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/stable/commands/init.html)

Comment: You should first find out where that alias is defined. Do you have a file calls `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` in your home folder? Check those for an `alias` and remove the relevant line from it

Answer (score 1):

Don't symlink a directory to an executable path that your system relies on to function.

I wouldn't really symlink conda at all since there are shell integrations to get a python environment from anywhere on the system. default system python should be reserved for system packages that rely on it, brew/apt/pacman ect will manage that for you to make sure the rest of you system works properly

try:

```
conda activate
```

if you get an error saying `conda command not found` or something like that navigate to the anaconda3/bin directory and type

```
./conda init
```

this will run the init script for shell integration, it will automatically look at your home directory to determine what shell you use and append a patch to your RC file to make sure you have conda command access anywhere.

after that restart your terminal (required)

type

```
conda activate
```

you should get `(base)` added to your prompt($PS1)
this means you are now in the base environment for conda
this is a special environment for conda that all other environments inherit from.

From here you can use

```
conda env create --name <env_name> python==<version i.e 3.9.6, 3.9, 3.10 or pretty much any other version number>
```

then

```
conda activate <env_name>
```

this will put you in your conda environment named whatever you put for <env_name> with the packages that were in base and the version of python that you specified

from here

`pip install <package>`

or (preferably)

`conda install <package>`

to get new packages

if you want to use conda-forge use

```
conda install -c conda-forge <package>
```

you can also just follow the [official install guide](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/mac-os/) on their website.

I'd start from the bottom where it shows

```
source /PATH/TO/ANACONDA/bin/activate
conda init
```

*Note: conda and anaconda are interchangeable when refering to anaconda. I prefer conda since that is the name of the actual command and refers to the name of the software not the entire package distribution*

Comment: Conda is activated and init shows a list of paths, at the end it says no action taken. What I am trying to do is run a file using conda from the terminal, but whenever I use python command it uses my default python version and I dont want that.
What other options do I have?

Comment: I have made the environment and all but yet, it is running on the default instead.

Comment: When you are activated on a conda env and you call python from that same shell you are using the conda env python.

for instance:

`conda env create --name my-python-10 python==3.10`

`python --version`

3.9.6

`conda activate my-python-10`

`python --version`

3.10.0

is that the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: To Answer the "how do I run a file from conda?"

after activating an env you would just run

`python /path/to/file.py`

that will run the python from the env that is selected

Comment: If you are trying to use conda from an IDE most of them have a place in the settings to specify a conda executable path. From the IDE it will let you either discover or set the available envs that can be used during execution.

Answer (score 0):

Add a symlink under /usr/local/bin, as it takes precedence over /usr/bin/.

```
ln -s /Users/siddhpurohit/anaconda3 /usr/local/bin/python
ln -s /Users/siddhpurohit/anaconda3 /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Also you can move /Users/siddhpurohit/anaconda3 under /usr/local/bin or ~/.local/bin, but you still need symlinks.

If you need multiple python versions then I suggest that you look into [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Comment: I did not understan what you are trying to say, can you be more specific?(also I did not downvote you)